# What kind of IPC have event for notify?

Tags: c#, .net, ipc

the case is, user will open a aspx to look for file generated in runtime. Such file is generated my a managed window service at the beginning design.

Now I am considering to have a IPC between aspx and the window service, so when I have a request from the user, I can send a message to windows service. After it is done, send back the file path and then open it in aspx.

I have a look about IPCChannel, Named Pipe and shared memory ...seems they are not very good on this purpose ...

Actually, the function just like filesystemwatcher ...When a message come, raise a event and I response ...

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Try revising your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that a website uses a request/reply architecture which doesn't work very well with event driven architecture (which usually is asynchronous).

The easiest approach is probably to let the windows service host a WCF service which you call from your web application.